# Rounded 3D Text Style?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, text-object

I am attempting to make some text which is not flat, and has a circular bevel and spherical caps. I found a good example of what I am trying to make:

[image]

As you can see, it is mainly composed of "pill" shapes. I can probably model this somewhat quickly, however, I need many of these styled letters in order to form some readable text and I do not want to make each of them one by one.

The desired workflow would be to first create a text object, and then turning it into the end result. However, I have a lot of trouble finding a simple way to turn text into something like this.

Comment: I think that you have no other choice but to find a font that looks round, use it as a blueprint and to recreate it with basic shapes and booleans, it should be fast though as it's a rather simple font